# Using Abel's test for negative coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

For the power series representation of

> $$\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{-z^n}{n},$$

is Abel's test still valid to conclude that the $\log(1-z)$ will converge everywhere on the unit disk, except at $z=1$?

Abel's test requires the coefficients to be positive however in this case my coefficients are $a_n=\frac{-1}{n}$.

Comment: Is there any problem taking the series for -Log$\,(1-z)\;$ ?

Comment: Make sure you have got the right power series.

Answer (score 1):

Abel's test really only requires that all the coefficients are the same sign eventually, not whether they're all positive or negative, and not depending on what the signs are for finitely many leading terms. To see this, consider $-f(x)$ instead of $f(x)$ if necessary, and subtract any leading terms in the series which have a different sign from the eventual sign.